# GIT Fork and Contributions

Tags: git, github

So I made a fork of a friends package and made edits and then requested a pull.
The changes were made however I did not get listed on the contributors because its a pull from my fork. In the end I just ended up making a manual edit to his read me and i got listed as just a readme editor.

I am wondering is there a way to amend this so my edits show correctly?

Comment: Did your friend actually accept your pull request?

Comment: Yeah they are all in his master now. If i manually edit his file from his git they show. If i fork and push and make a request they dont show as mine but his.

Comment: @Oxymoron updated comment forgot mention

Comment: So you've made a fork, then you cloned your fork to your local machine, modified some files, committed that back up to your fork and created a PR?

Comment: @Oxymoron this is correct. https://github.com/michaelmano its the snippets 1

Comment: Ah, I see. One moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing your repository your commits are being made under the username "Administrator". So GitHub doesn't know who's who. You want to follow these tutorials on github

1) [Setup your username in git-scm](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/)

2) [Setup your email in git-scm](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/)

Comment: Thank you so much. Once i update this do you know if it will fix the contributors on his?

Comment: You will probably have to do another pull request. possibly doing `git commit --amend` on your side, and go through the process again.